# Is it possible to have Multi Maven Module inside Multi Maven Module?

Tags: java, maven, architecture

Is it possible to have nested multi maven modules?

For example, I created a Project called "architecture" that is composed of multiple maven modules, but one of them (architecture_utils) is becoming very big, so for organizational purposes, I would like to split them into separate maven modules and have the following structure:

```
architecture
  ├── architecture_base
  ├── architecture_test
  └── architecture_utils
       ├── architecture_utils_io
       ├── architecture_utils_math
       └── architecture_utils_time
```

1. is that possible?
2. any good reason not to do that? (alternatives?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, it is possible. Architecture and Architecture-utils will just be aggregators, calling their submodules.
2. you described one good reason why you want to to have separate modules.